# How to set Binding to TextBox that is inside of UserControl from mainpage?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

When I'm doing this nothing happens.
Code behind

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty prop = DependencyProperty.Register("Prop", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), null);

public string Prop
{
    get { return this.GetValue(prop) as string; }
    set { this.SetValue(prop, value); }
}
```

XAML of UserControl

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Prop}"></TextBox>
```

XAML of MainPage

```
<xx:MyUserControl Prop="{Binding Name}"></xx:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: Try giving ElementName. Text="{Binding Prop,ElementName =usercontrolname}

Comment: Also you can add `(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;` in your `UserControl`'s constructor. See Jerry Nixon's blog: [Walkthrough: Two-way binding inside a XAML User Control](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html).

Answer (score 0):

Give `ElementName`.

```
Text="{Binding Prop,ElementName =usercontrolname}
```